# block variables using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i need to block some numbers in my input field. I got the blocked numbers in a mysql table:

```
id|number
 1 |1234
 2 |3456
```

What i tryed:

```
<?
include("connect.php");


 $mb1=GetRow("SELECT number FROM mblock WHERE id=1");
 $mb2=GetRow("SELECT number FROM mblock WHERE id=2");

 ?>

 <script type='text/javascript'     src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2'></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="write here"  />
 Number to block:<?echo $mb1;?>
<p></p>
<script>
 var badWords = ['$mb1', "2222", "3333", "4444"];

 $("input").keyup(function(){
for(var i = 0; i < badWords.length; i++)
{
    if(this.value == badWords[i])
    {
       this.value ="";
        return;
    }        
 }
 })
 </script>
```

The .php is retrieving the number, but the is not blocking. The other numbers is blocking (2222,3333,4444)

Thx

Comment: View the source, and see what $mb1 is outputting in the array, any spaces or other weirdness will make your function faulty.

Comment: why not do this on the server side before inserting (or whatever you need done with them) instead of relying on some js that users can disable

Comment: I did it in the server side as well, if the user copy/paste a blocked number the jquery won´t work, but the .php will.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't `var badWords = ['$mb1', "2222", "3333", "4444"];`

be `var badWords = ['<?php echo $mb1;?>', "2222", "3333", "4444"];`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you included jQuery library to your html file?

Comment: Yes. The numbers var badWords = ["2222", "3333", "4444"]; is blocking. Only the $mb1 isn´t.